Why does systemd change the cpuset of a service
I have a process that is invoked by systemd using the following basic syntax in a file named /lib/systemd/system/application-runapp.service:
[Unit]
Description=Application Service - Multi Threaded
After=network.target auditd.service sshd.service
[Service]
Type=exec
EnvironmentFile=-/usr/lib/application/application.options
ExecStart=/usr/lib/application/runapp $APPLICATION_OPTIONS
CPUAffinity=0-15
StandardOutput=null
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=application-runapp.service
And then the service is enabled:
sudo systemctl enable application-runapp.service
sudo systemctl start application-runapp.service
This process has 12 threads instantiated by pthread_create() and with CPU affninity being set using pthread_setaffinity_np().
Under normal workload, 10 out of the 12 threads will run approximately 30% CPU. The other 2 threads are not very busy.  Essentially each of these 12 threads using setaffinity is set to CPU cores 0 through 11.
I have installed this application using Ubuntu 22.04 Virtual Machine running in ESXi and it is running with 16 CPU Cores assigned by ESXi to the VM.
When running the application, I can use HTOP to see each of the 12 threads assigned to the appropriate cores CPU 0 through 11 and running fine.
After some time (roughly 2-3 mintues), I notice that the CPU threads will no longer be locked to these 12 CPU cores but rather will be assigned to CPU Cores 0-7 or CPU Cores 8-15. I am not sure why it will be one or the other set. But the key thing is that they will only be running in the first 8 or last 8 CPU cores.
And I can verify that using the taskset -c -p PID will return the following when the CPUs are properly aligned to the 12 threads:
user@hostname21:~$ taskset -c -p 1292
pid 1292's current affinity list: 0-15
And I can verify that using the taskset -c -p PID will return the following when the CPUs are NOT properly aligned to the 12 threads:
user@hostname21:~$ taskset -c -p 1292
pid 1292's current affinity list: 8-15
But then I can use the following command to reset the affinity list:
user@hostname21:~$ sudo taskset -pc 0-15 1292
pid 1292's current affinity list: 8-15
pid 1292's new affinity list: 0-15
I have tried many things with the systemd configurations to attempt to fix this problem with no success.
I did modify my application to periodically (once per second) use pthread_getaffinity_np() to determine the CPU_SET assigned to each thread. And if the expected CPU is not properly detected, the application thread will then refresh the affinity using pthread_setaffinity_np() for each thread. And while the requested affinity set using taskset -c -p PID returns the current affinity of 8-15, the threads will automatically realign to the proper CPU cores. However, this is not a good solution to the problem.
I also can verify that this problem does NOT happen if I simply run the application from a command line rather than starting the service through systemd.
I assume this is easy to explain and how to configure the appropriate service file or modify /etc/systemd/system.conf to correct the issue.
Thank you,
Dominick
